# Constrain array values to keys of interface

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to constrain an array's values to particular keys of an interface:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: string;
  baz: number;
  foo: string;
}

type ExtractArrayOfKeys<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, K>[];

const keyArray: ExtractArrayOfKeys<Foo, "bar" | "baz"> = ["bar", "baz"]; // Error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Pick<Foo, "bar" | "baz">'
```

Comment: `Array<keyof Foo>`

Comment: @bugs I wish to pick particular keys... So in the above, how could I type the array to allow `bar` and `baz` as valid entries, but disallow `foo`?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question...

Comment: No worries, all good :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done relatively easily with the [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) utility type, something like

```js
type AllFoo = keyof Foo
type BarBaz = Extract<keyof Foo, 'bar' | 'baz'>

const allFooOK: AllFoo[] = ['bar', 'baz', 'foo']
const allFooNotOK: AllFoo[] = ['bar', 'kek'] // Type '"kek"' is not assignable to type '"bar" | "baz" | "foo"'

const barBazOK: BarBaz[] = ['bar', 'baz']
const barBazNotOK: BarBaz[] = ['bar', 'foo'] // Type '"foo"' is not assignable to type '"bar" | "baz"'.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIBGcUAXMgM5hSgDmA3PkXAF7kgCuAtodIwTEzkqNEA1wBfXLjABPAA4oAggBsVGLAF5kAawiz0MNJhkKUAIRKWWybQFEAHtURgAPHoNGNAGmQByYig-ZAAff2IWPwA+aQR0ECpkODUNAHkAaXJVdUwAbQBdW2RcgJI-X1LIisF0P3zcOISwJJTMADl0MAys1vQCopLA8v89HTrkAHoJ5AAVM38AIlGF4OAKZBBOpIoKYFoQOEIVFDAsOUVFwIXQ5AWI67CFmpXY+MTA627kSyhrfu1BmUKhE6g03s0PqwOl1Mt8rKx-sVSkFqphxlNZvM-E9MCtkGsNls4Ds9gcjiczli7iQHrd7n4AHRAA)